# Delete rows in sqlite where number of rows with a number are < 1

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Currently I have code that goes through my sqlite database and gets the number of rows with a number equals 1. if that is the case I delete the row with that number. It works well but I was wondering if I could do the same in sqlite only instead of doing all this looping and constant pegging of the badtadase.

here is the code I currently have

```
public void deleteSession(){
    ArrayList<long> numbers = getScannedNumbers();

    for(int i=0; i<numbers.size(); i++){
        int count = getRowCount(numbers.get(i).number);
        if(count == 1){
            //delete that row
        }
    }
}
```

`getScannedNumbers` returns a list of numbers (basically identifiers) from the database where a column called `scan_count` is > 0

`getRowCount` returns the number of rows that have the number as an identifier

can this be done as a single sql delete statement or is what I am doing with all the looping going to be my solution?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein No I want to delete all records that have a `scan_count > 0 unless that record has an identifier that is in the db multiple times. If a record has an identifier that is in there multiple times i want to keep them

Comment: Can you post your database schema somehow?  I'm not clear on how many tables there are and where the fields are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you.

```
DELETE FROM mytab
WHERE myid IN 
(
    SELECT myid
    FROM mytab
    GROUP BY myid
    HAVING count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: changed the > 1 to == 1 and it does exactly what I want